# error opening socket in program on network location

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-update

I develop software from a network location. Until recently this works without problems. But after the last Windows 10 update (may 2018) something changed. Programs still run from this location but when I try to open a socket I get the error 'invalid argument (10022)'. The code is so basic:

```
Socket s;
s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

Running it from a local disk doesn't produce the error.

A sample program with with a single button will generate this error condition.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Socket s;
    try
    {
        s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + error.Message);
        return;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Oke");
}
```

Any thoughts how to proceed?

Comment: What is the full error message? Edit your question with it and you might get some answers.

Comment: The full message is 'Er is een ongeldig argument opgegeven', but the error code is 10022: InvalidArgument. My translation was indeed wrong.